# Microsoft SQL Server : getting highest cost for last purchase date

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's been a while since I used SQL so I'm a bit rusty. Let's say you want to compare the cost of things purchased from the previous month to this month. So an example would be a data table like this...

[image: Sample Data]

An item purchased on October cost $3 but the same item cost in September was $2 and $1. So you'd get the max cost of the max date (which would then be the $2 not $1). This would happen for every row of data.

I've done this with a stored scalar-value function, but when handling 100K+ rows of data, speeds are no where near fast. How would you do this with a select query in itself? What I did before was select both the max's in a select statement and only return 1, then call that function in a select statement. I want to do the same without stored procedures or functions for speed reasons. I know the following query won't work because you can only return 1 value, but it's something that I'm going for.

```
Select 
    Purchase, Item, USD, 
    (select MAX(Purchase), MAX(USD) from Table 
     where Item = 845 and MONTH(Purchase) = MONTH(Purchase) -1) LastCost 
from Table
```

An example of what it should display can be portrayed as this.

[image]

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, item, usd, 
  LAG(Date, 1) OVER(Order by date asc) as FormerDate,
  LAG(usd, 1) OVER(Order by date asc) as FormerUsd 
from (select date, item, max(usd) as usd from Data group by date, item) t
```

This basically returns the day before the current entry with its max price.

Comment: I like this method, but I can see a problem with it as it returns the last date, not the max last date of the month before.

Comment: try this (without window function): `select t.Date, t.item, t.usd, j.usd as LastUsd
    from Data t
    left outer join 
    (select month(date) as month, year(date) as year, item, max(usd) as usd 
    from Data group by month(date), year(date), item) j
     on j.month = month(t.date)-1 and j.year = year(t.date) and j.item = t.item` tested this with some data and seems to be correct

Comment: This is a very solid answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Attention:** 
`Select MAX(Purchase), MAX(USD) from Table` will not return the highest cost for the highest date, but will return the highest date and the highest cost (no matter of what date).

This is how I would do this (on at least SQL Server 2012):

To get only one record per month and item (with the highest cost on the latest date), I use a numbering for the purchase date and cost (per item and month) with a descending sort order, first by date, then by cost. In the next step, I filter out only those records where the numbering is 1 (max cost for max date per item and month) and use the LAG function to access the previous cost:

```
WITH 
  numbering (Purchase, Item, Cost, p_no) AS (
    SELECT Purchase,Item, Cost
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item, EOMONTH(Purchase) ORDER BY Purchase DESC, Cost DESC)
    FROM tbl
  )
SELECT Purchase, Item, Cost
  , LAG(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Purchase) AS LastCost
FROM numbering
WHERE p_no = 1
```

Comment: I think it might be possible for rows to come out with (p_no, c_no) as (1, 2) and (2, 1). In other words you don't have a single row of (1, 1).

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, but no, this isn't possible. `p_no` is a numbering of the purchase dates and `c_no` is a numbering of the cost values per date, so for each date (`p_no`) there must be a row with `c_no = 1`.

Comment: I think if you had ties between both date and cost that SQL Server wouldn't guarantee both row-numberings to be in the same sequence.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thank you, that's right. I changed my answer to use the `RANK` function for the numbering of the dates, that should solve the problem with the ties.

Comment: Simplified my answer using only one numbering.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL server 2017 below query will work for sample data

```
select purchase,item,
substring(usd,CHARINDEX(',',usd),len(usd)) as USD,
substring(usd,1,CHARINDEX(',',usd)) as lastcost from
(select max(purchase) as purchase,item, STRING_AGG (usd, ',') AS usd
 from
(
 select  purchase,item,max(usd) as usd from t
group by purchase,item

) as T group by item
) T1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your results, you need to use `MAX()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` with `OVER()`. Then partition the records by Item, Year, and Month. This will assure that the sort will be on each item, by each year, by each month. The `ROW_NUMBER()` will act as as simple way to put the last records at the top of the results, so you'll call row number 1 for each item to get the latest cost. After that, you use it as subquery to refine it as needed. For a start (your sample), you'll need to use `CASE` in order to split the USD (previous and Last cost). then you do the rest from there (simple methods).

I need to note that it's important to sort the records by year first, then month. then if you need to include the day, include it. This way you'll insure the records will be sorted correctly.

So, the query would look like something like this :

```
SELECT 
    MAX(Purchase) Purchase
,   MAX(Item) Item
,   MAX(CASE WHEN LastCost > USD THEN LastCost ELSE NULL END) USD
,   MAX(CASE WHEN LastCost = USD THEN LastCost ELSE NULL END) LastCost 
FROM (
SELECT 
    Purchase
,   Item
,   USD
,   MAX(USD) OVER(PARTITION BY Item, YEAR(Purchase), MONTH(Purchase)) LastCost
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item, YEAR(Purchase), MONTH(Purchase) ORDER BY MONTH(Purchase)) RN
FROM Table
) D     
WHERE 
    RN = 1
```

Comment: May I ask what's the RN=1 in the where clause?

Comment: @Thatguy row number (last column of D subselect)

Comment: @Thatguy as revoua said. I used ROW_NUMBER() to resorder the results in DESC. so the max month, price will always be at the first row (row number 1).

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select Item, eomonth(Purchase) as PurchaseMonth, max(USD) as MaxUSD
    from T
    group by Item, eomonth(Purchase)
  )
select
    PurchaseMonth, Item,
    lag(MaxUSD) over (partition by Item order by PurchaseMonth) as PriorUSD
from data;
```